# Loop through particular row in a DataTable

Tags: vb.net, datatable

Following code gives values in the 8th column. Following code is okay.

```
Dim myDataTable As System.Data.DataTable = New System.Data.DataTable
For Each row As System.Data.DataRow In myDataTable.Rows
    MessageBox.Show(row.Item(7).ToString)
Next
```

Following code doesn't give values in the 8th row. Following code is not okay.

```
Dim myDataTable As System.Data.DataTable = New System.Data.DataTable
For Each col As System.Data.DataColumn In myDataTable.Columns
    MessageBox.Show(col.Item(7).ToString)
Next
```

Any suggestion?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `DataColumn` class doesn't have an `Item` property. If you want to iterate through the items of the 8th row, you can do so using the `ItemArray` property of the DataRow:

```
For Each item In myDataTable.Rows(7).ItemArray
    MessageBox.Show(item.ToString)
Next
```

Comment: @JohnyL I'm assuming you mean what you did in your answer, which is essentially the same thing except you're using `DataRow.Item(index)` instead of iterating the `ItemArray`. Still, the `DataColumn` class does **Not** have an `Item` property as I mentioned above. So, I'm not sure what you mean by your comment or what you _might_ think is wrong with the answer!

Answer (score 0):

```
Dim dt As New DataTable()
Dim eightRow = dt.Rows(7)
For x = 0 To dt.Columns.Count - 1
    MessageBox.Show(eightRow(x).ToString())
Next
```